# Is it possible to determine the top users of SqlServer analysis services?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server

We're trying to figure out how many licenses we need of a desktop data analysis package which connects directly to our SSAS instance.

I'd like know if it's possible to query the history of connection or queries by user so we can determine who is actively using the software.

I've looked into $system.DISCOVER_SESSIONS, but it seems that it only contains current sessions. I'd like get historical activity.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it, but Microsoft has an [activity monitoring tool](http://asactivityviewer2008.codeplex.com/) for SSAS 2008 out on CodePlex.

Comment: looks like it only show current activity

Comment: @Scott: it looks like it pulls the user activity data out of `$system.discover_sessions` - perhaps you can use this to create your own store procedure that creates a history?

Comment: Indeed, a plan for the future

Comment: I did something similar with sp_who to get a historical log of SQL Server connection activity. Basically I have a stored procedure that runs sp_who and parses the results into a table, as well as a job that runs the proc every 10 minutes.

Comment: as i remeber the licencing you dont need to count. at SQL Level is enough when you know that the Company has 400 users sofar they need 400 cals thats it this is due the fact that they have a Passus inside which User they *could* access to it even they dont do

Answer (score 0):

yes you have two options  for monitoring

setup the query log:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917676.aspx

or run profiler:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174779(v=SQL.90).aspx

i would recommend trying both and seeing which one works best for you.